# Copy & Paste Multiline CSS (Chrome DevTools)

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

One of the newer updates of Google Chrome, or a setting of mine, has changed so the output of copying CSS styles from an element suddenly goes on multiple lines. Is there an option to make it go back to outputting on a single line?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in devtools.

Comment: A workaround is to right click the rules and choose "copy all declarations" - when pasted, it outputs in single line